# Output resistance of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance, output, equivalent-circuit

While studying amplifiers, I came across the AC equivalent circuit of an amplifier:

[image]

To calculate the output resistance of the amplifier, the input signal was set to zero and the load resistance was removed as shown in the figure:

[image: w]

What is the reason for doing so?

Link to the PDF I am referring to is [here](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/%7Esequel/ee230/mbpth_ce_amp.pdf).

Comment: By driving the output with another signal of known impedance, with 0 input, one can compute Ro by the attenuation.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering. I guess you should also show us the derivation of \$R_O\$.

Comment: @user2233709 I have linked the PDF. It shows the calculation of output resistance.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't get it. Could you please explain?

Comment: It tells you esentially to use Fig 6 b) to test for Ro just like Ri

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What would happen if the input is not kept constant? How will it affect the output and the resistance?

Comment: You can vary DC, but for Ro you want to measure matching R from an external AC signal /2 from no load or any ratio you can compute.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the Thévenin equivalent circuit, you set voltage sources to zero (make voltage sources shorts) and calculate the impedance between the nodes with no load. That's all that's happening here. It's just explicitly showing that the dependent voltage source is also zero (a short). That means the output impedance is whatever R<sub>0</sub> is.

In the PDF they also describe how you can use that to measure the output impedance as Tony Stewart points out in the comments.

Comment: So we have to consider the thevenin equivalent circuit while calculating the output impedance ?

Comment: It's a way of doing it (assuming the model is appropriate). Thevenin equivalence basically reduces things to voltage sources + output resistance. It works if your model is linearized (in other words approximated) around some operating point (that is,  q point).