# Output resistance in negative feedback

Tags: amplifier, resistance, voltage-source, negative-feedback

I was studying negative feedback in voltage amplifiers. I found this on Wikipedia for calculating input resistance as shown below.

[image]

Following the similar method, I tried to calculate the output resistance with feedback \$Z_{of}\$.

Connected a voltage source \$V_o\$ which supplies a current \$I_o\$. Applying Kirchoff's voltage law to the output loop, we have

\$V_o = I_oZ_o + A_v.V_{in}\$

For negative feedback, \$V_{in} = V_x - V_f\$ and \$V_f = \beta V_o\$. Therefore

\$V_o = I_oZ_o + A_v.(V_x - \beta V_o)\$

\$V_o = I_oZ_o + A_v.V_x - A_v.\beta V_o\$

\$V_o + A_v.\beta V_o = I_oZ_o + A_v.V_x\$

\$V_o(1 + A_v.\beta) = I_oZ_o + A_v.V_x\$

Dividing both the sides by \$I_o\$, we get

\$Z_{of} = \frac{Z_o}{(1 + A_v.\beta)} + \frac{(A_v.V_x)}{(I_o)(1 + A_v.\beta)}\$

The above expression is what I am getting. But the answer is \$Z_{of} = \frac{Z_o}{(1 + A_v.\beta)}\$. I am getting an extra term \$\frac{(A_v.V_x)}{(I_o)(1 + A_v.\beta)}\$.

What is the mistake in my calculation? Please help.

Comment: [Related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/565339). This may answer your question. You need to assume that input voltage is zero.

Comment: In V=IR, R is the slope of the voltage vs current line.  Therefore R is the *change* in output voltage with *change* in output current.  Since you are only looking at changes, you can ignore the extra constant term (Av.Vx)/(1 + Av.B).

Comment: @AJN I looked up the internet and found out the same, input signal is assumed zero. But  what may the reason of doing so? To eliminate the extra term?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242397/why-should-we-set-input-source-equal-zero-for-calculating-output-resistance-of-c/242453#242453